# unabel to resolve dependencies using maven

Tags: java, dependencies, repository, maven-3

I am running maven 3.8.9 and this is what i have in pom.xml

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

This is what i have in settings.xml

```
   <mirror>
      <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
      <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>
      <blocked>true</blocked>
    </mirror>
```

I get Below error not sure what i am missing

```
        Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:jar:2.3.0.RC1
     -> org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:jar:5.3.1.RELEASE 
-> com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:7.1.1 -> com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:8.8
 -> net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3]: No versions available for net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3] within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: boot 2.3 was released back in 2020. Why trying to use a release-candidate? Why using such an old version at all?

Comment: yes i just noticed, i downloaded a reactive project from online and working through it for my own project. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pull a dependency (not a plugin), define an entry in `repositories` (not `pluginRepositories`). That easy.

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: i used java for 10 years and always thought having https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 in the repository section is enough, i learn new things every day or never learned a thing in 10 years :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the index file of this artifact in Maven Central is outdated. From ~/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata-nexus.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.3.1</latest>
    <release>1.3.1</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </versions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Nexus shows me that the file hasn't been updated in Maven Central since 2019.

When I change `1.3.1` to `2.4.10` in my local file the build continues.

Comment: I've just sent an email to Maven Central.